# Would it be helpful/possible to come up with a canonical answer for "I want to switch from Windows XP to Ubuntu?"

Tags: discussion

With Windows XP dead, I would imagine many people not willing to fork over 120 bucks for Windows 7 will be looking at Ubuntu as a possible solution.

I have seen a couple questions along those lines.

Example:[Access to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445617/access-to-ubuntu).

And I've seen some other recently that I can't track down right now.

Anticipating more to come and hoping to convert some Windows users.

Would some community members smarter than myself, like to work on crafting a really good Q & A to help people that are totally new to Ubuntu? I know there are a lot of question about installing Ubuntu, and if this Q & A already exists just point me there please.

Comment: What particular question are you referring to? We don't do extremely broad "What should I know coming from XP" type questions (unless worded ***very*** carefully). We have a couple questions on installing Ubuntu, installing Windows software, etc.

Comment: Hmm, maybe what I'm talking about already exists.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are talking about? What specific question do you think we could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phenomenon you're describing has been going on longer than the day Windows XP has been unsupported. We have a buttload of existing "how to migrate" questions.

So why not merge them all into one? Well a migration has to account for *all* of the following in order to really be successful.

- Do I actually want to do this? (a fairly important bit we're blinkered against)
- Will my hardware support it?
- How do I migrate *safely*? (data loss is an instant disgruntled user)
- What alternative applications will I use now?
- How can I keep running my old apps?
- How do I do X with random-hardware-Y that only has Windows support?

You could write a book on this stuff and still not cover it all. When you start considering answers like that, it's probably time you went to the Ubuntu Wiki and started writing. That's the place for documentation like that IMO.

Comment: At very least, the questions should have tried something and don't get the expected results. But, and here applies the golden rule, OP should always do backups.